# How to rearrage the data which is in a txt file

Tags: c#, parsing, file-handling

I am trying to format a raw data feedback from my servo driver which saved in a txt file. The data is position and voltage of servo motor in every 10 ms.

The position data is suppose to be in one line and the voltage data in another line ideally but they don't and sometime there is error messages also in between datas.

Since the data contains many errors and sometimes two data are gets merged together I am arranging the data manually in that txt file where the data is saved.

While arranging data in the txt file manually , first I separate the data.

The first data is position data (for eg. 6130.0438232) which always has 12 characters (including '.'dot) and the voltage data (looks like 0.0908446) 9 character(including '.' dot). Please see the picture attached for information.

The thing is I want to do this manually and want to check all the character in the txt file and format it according to my need as shown in figure.

I hope you guys can give suggestions regarding it.

[image]

[Files are available in this link too](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/453393-reading-txt-file-organizing-data-and-saving-formatted-data-into-excel?s_tid=prof_contriblnk)

Raw Data:

```
>
>
6130.0
438232
0.0910353
!FF10
0.0910317

!FF10

!FF10

!FF10

!FF10

6130.0438232
!
FF10
6130.0438232
0.0908446

6130.0438232
0.1517510
6130.0438232
0.
1518797

613
0.0438232
0.1136887
6130.0438232
0.1133942

6130.0438232
0.0917661
6130.0438232
!FF10

32
5.7181644
!FF02
0.0912833

6130.0438232
!FF10
!FF10
0.0910270

6130.
0438232
0.0907409
6130.0438232
0.0907421

6130.043823
2
0.0906980
6130.0438232
0.0906491

6130.0438232
0.
1557195
6130.0438232
!FF10

6130.0438232
0.09
08780
!FF10
0.0908589

6130.0438232
0.0905549
6130.0438232
0.
0905442
```

Comment: Post that raw data as a code snippet.

Comment: You said: "The first data is position data (for eg. 6130.0438232) which always has 12 characters (including '.'dot) "  But is it always four digits before the dot?  Or will it always be twelve characters with the dot **anywhere** within those twelve?

Comment: position data is 6130.04388232 mm (value also contain decimal numbers) actually there is 12 character in above  data which represent position of servo( 11 number and one dot) .

Comment: Nevermind.  The 325 line only has 11 characters, not 12.  Also, what other error messages are possible?  I see `!FF10` and `!FF02`.  It is **always** `!F` followed by two digits?  You have to be very specific.

Comment: yes the error are always followed by !F and the 325 line (I cannot find the exact line) might have some data missing which is why its 11 characters. Actually I will have to remove those errors and will have to place the interpolated data in the invalid values.

Comment: If you have "errors", we won't be of much help here.  For consecutive numbers that don't have exactly 9 or 12 digits, how well we know where one number stops, and the next one starts?!

Comment: actually the position data will always be in between '6130 to 6330' and I have a rough idea of voltage feedback (0 to 10max) so I am able to differentiate the data manually.

Comment: "I have a rough idea of voltage feedback (0 to 10max)" So for voltage, there could be a `10.xxx` value?  Again,  how would we know if that first `1` (one) is supposed to go with the previous position number (with a possible "error"), or the voltage number,  which could be `10.xxx` or `0.xxx`?

Answer (score 1):

For fun, I made a first attempt at your problem. Here is the output based on the supplied input file `"RawData.txt"`

[image: scr]

and below is the code used to generate this output:

```
public struct DataPoint
{
    // The fields below default to 0 which are interpreted as hadn't been
    // set yet. If the value is negative then it represents an error,
    // and if the value is positive it is set.

    public float Position;
    public float Voltage;
    public const string Error = "!FF10";

    // Check the both fields are non-zero (have been set).
    public bool IsOK => Position!=0 && Voltage!=0;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Convert the two fields into a comma separated string line

        var pos_str = Position>0 ? Position.ToString() :
            Position==0 ? string.Empty : DataPoint.Error;
        var vlt_str = Voltage>0 ? Voltage.ToString() :
            Voltage==0 ? string.Empty : DataPoint.Error;

        return $"{pos_str},{vlt_str}";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Process in the data and generate an array of DataPoint
        DataPoint[] input = ProcessFile(File.OpenText("RawData.txt"));

        // Display the items in the array as a table in the console
        int index = 0;
        // Three columns with widths, 5, 12 and 9
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Index",-5} {"Pos",-12} {"Volts",-9}");
        foreach (DataPoint item in input)
        {
            index++;
            // Each DataPoint contains data (floating point numbers),
            // and can be converted into a comma separated string using
            // the .ToString() method.
            var parts = item.ToString().Split(',');
            Console.WriteLine($"{index,-5} {parts[0],-12} {parts[1],-9}");
        }

    }

    static DataPoint[] ProcessFile(StreamReader reader)
    {
        var list = new List<DataPoint>();
        // current data to be filled by reader
        DataPoint data = new DataPoint();
        // keep track if the next input is for
        // position or voltage.
        bool expect_position_value = false;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
            // each line is either:
            // * blank
            // * position data, 12 char, numeric
            // * voltage data, 9 char, numeric
            // * error code "!FF10"

            // but random line feeds exist in the file.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                // empty line, do nothing
                continue;
            }
            if (line.StartsWith(">"))
            {
                // prompt line, do nothing
                continue;
            }
            // flip the expected value between position & voltage
            expect_position_value=!expect_position_value;
            if (!line.StartsWith(DataPoint.Error) 
                    && line.Length!=9 && line.Length!=12)
            {
                // Data was split by a line feed. Read
                // next line and combine together.
                var next = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
                Debug.WriteLine(next);
                line+=next;
            }
            if (line.StartsWith(DataPoint.Error))
            {
                // Error value
                if (expect_position_value)
                {
                    data.Position=-1;
                }
                else
                {
                    data.Voltage=-1;
                }
                if (data.IsOK)
                {
                    list.Add(data);
                    data=new DataPoint();
                    expect_position_value=false;
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (line.Length==12)
            {
                // position value
                if (float.TryParse(line, out float position))
                {
                    data.Position=position;
                    expect_position_value=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // cannot read position, what now?
                }
            }
            if (line.Length==9)
            {
                // voltage value
                if (float.TryParse(line, out float voltage))
                {
                    data.Voltage=voltage;
                    expect_position_value=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // cannot read voltage. what now?
                }
            }
            if (data.IsOK)
            {
                // data has been filled. Add to list and get
                // ready for next data point.
                list.Add(data);
                data=new DataPoint();
            }
        }
        // Export array of data.
        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Enjoy!